# Maneras de añadir un valor en un diccionario

Tags: python, python-3.x

En un curso de python dice que una de las maneras de añadir un elemento en un diccionario dice que se puede hacer así:

```
diccionario = update("keyPrueba" : "10")
```

Pero al intentar correrlo me marca error de sintaxis, en cambio, si puedo hacerlo de esta manera:

```
diccionario[keyPrueba] = 10
```

¿En algún momento quitaron esa opción de aplicar update o el curso está mal? He intentado distintas formas de aplicar el update y no lo consigo.

Nota: En el siguiente ejemplo entiendo que tratan a update como un método pero en el curso lo expresan también como mostré anteriormente.

```
d1 = {'Adam Smith':'A', 'Judy Paxton':'B+'}
d2 = {'Mary Louis':'A', 'Patrick White':'C'}
d3 = {}

for item in (d1, d2):
    d3.update(item)

print(d3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nunca a existido un builtin `update` que haga esto, tendría poco sentido además dado que sería algo muy específico de un diccionario,
Es más, la sintaxis, `update("keyPrueba" : "10")`ni siquiera sería válida, en todo caso `update("keyPrueba", "10")`.

Aclarar que las dos formas que muestras no son lo mismo:

- `diccionario[keyPrueba] = 10` permite asignar una nueva pareja clave valor al diccionario. Si existe una clave con el mismo nombre queda substituido su valor por el nuevo (reasigna) ya que un diccionario por definición no puede tener duplicados.
- El método `dict.update` por contra recibe **otro diccionario, o secuencia de parejas clave-valor como argumento**:

  - Si una clave del diccionario pasado como argumento existe en el que va a ser actualizado se substituye su valor por el nuevo valor.
  - Si una clave del diccionario pasado como argumento no existe en el que va a ser actualizado se agrega la nueva pareja clave-valor.
  - Si una clave existe en el diccionario a actualizar pero no en el pasado como argumento se deja como está.

  ---

  Puede ser llamado de tres formas distintas:

  - Con un diccionario:

    ```
    foo = {"a": 1, "b": 2 }
    foo.update({"a": 7, "c": 5})
    ```
  - Con un iterable con parejas clave-valor:

    ```
    foo = {"a": 1, "b": 2 }
    foo.update((["a", 7], ["c", 5]))
    ```
  - Usando argumentos tipo keyword:

    ```
    foo = {"a": 1, "b": 2 }
    foo.update(a=7, c=5)
    ```

  Es decir, como su nombre indica, actualiza un diccionario usando otro o una secuencia de parejas clave-valor.

  Tu ejemplo final es exactamente lo mismo que:

  ```
  d3 = {}
  d3.update({'Adam Smith':'A', 'Judy Paxton':'B+'})
  d3.update({'Mary Louis':'A', 'Patrick White':'C'})
  ```

Hay un tercer método que permite insertar valores en un diccionario que es `dict.setdefault(key, value)`. Si la clave existe retorna su valor, si no existe la agrega usando como valor el segundo argumento o None si no se especifica dicho argumento.

En Python 3.9 se van a agregar dos operadores que pueden operar con diccionarios:

- **`|=`**  que funciona como el método `dict.update`, in-place.
- **`|`** que realiza la misma operación pero generando un nuevo diccionario (merge)